# WordPress Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live' | thickbox.js:23

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, thickbox

In my WordPress admin area, under "Chrome Inspect Element>Console> I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live' |
>   thickbox.js:23

When I click `thickbox.js:23`, this is whats highlighted

```
//add thickbox to href & area elements that have a class of .thickbox
function tb_init(domChunk){
jQuery(domChunk).live('click', tb_click);
```

I get the same thing on my pages etc..

I have related this to my theme, which I've contacted them about, but no help yet.

Hoping someone could help me figure out whats happening here.

Comment: Did you link to jQuery script before adding thickbox ?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was removed in 1.9 in favor of [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: 1.8.3 its WP though, how come their not using the latest version? http://bit.ly/Li14sS after playing with it, now it says something else

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery version 9.1+, try adding [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme) plugin. Add following to functions.php

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_scripts' );
function admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-migrate','http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js',array('jquery'));
}
```